# An answer of mine switched questions

Tags: support, answers, duplicate-answers

[This answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165358/172011) miraculously appeared in that question after I only wrote [that answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173747/172011) to the question (now deleted though). But I recall writing the other answer for another question some time back.

Looking at the other answers to the question they are all mixed. Some from dates way before the question was asked.

What is going on here?

Comment: There are a few answers on that question that have timestamps that don't match the question.  It's like there was a time warp while someone was doing a merge.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/173740/timeline

Comment: I have a hunch that it may have something to do with that "anon" account suddenly appearing.  I've no proof or reason to suspect it, but it's a hunch nonetheless.

Comment: My bad - normally, I'd clean up duplicate answers like this when merging; somehow, I overlooked this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is on a comment under your [deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173747/162704):

> An older question was merged into this one. – Anna Lear ♦

So, what happened here was:

- There was an [older question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132890/what-stack-exchange-site-would-address-software-suggestion-questions) that was an exact duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173740/could-we-have-a-se-for-recommendations)
- The old question was closed as a duplicate of the new one (rare, but it happens when the newer question is better)
- The old question was merged to the new one and its answers where transferred on the new one
- You had an answer on the old question that was an almost exact duplicate of your answer on the new one, and there wasn't any point in keeping both around. I'm guessing Anna deleted your newer answer because it had less votes than the older one.

Comment: Yeah, basically. The newer answer didn't add anything that the older one didn't say. Specifically, here's the question that got merged: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132890/what-stack-exchange-site-would-address-software-suggestion-questions.