# Closing questions two years after they were opened, 10k views and answers with 10 or more upvotes

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My question I asked two years ago has just been closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751971/which-wysiwyg-javascript-html-text-editor-should-i-use-with-angularjs

2 years after it was asked, over 10k views and quite a few upvotes for answers and question.

Seriously... I think anything that has not been moderated/deleted for longer than half a year deserves a right to stay. Obviously people were interested in that kind of question and a lot of people approved the given answers.

I understand that it is an opinion based question, but it feels really awkward having it closed such a long time later! Did you just stumble over it or is it part of a "I'm so bored on my sunday campaign"? How comes it was fine for 2 years and now it's suddenly bad?

Comment: Complaints deserve punishment...?

Comment: Don't take downvotes personally or as "punishment". I'd say it is a perceived lack of research; the Stack Exchange moderation policies have been extensively discussed here. Your question is also kind-off off-topic here as there is a Stack Overflow specific Meta site for questions concerning posts on SO and their OT policies (which differ from site to site).

Comment: I actually thought I was posting in that specific meta SO space. My bad, these all look the same... Please excuse me, I got some policies to read and catch up now...

Comment: Please, take my downvote as punishment.

Comment: @Won't don't joke about it, "50 shades of SO" is already in production and you just earned the lead role

Comment: I shall take that as my punishment :(

Answer (score 10):

Don't confuse popularity with being on-topic. What is on-topic does change over time, and what we *don't* want is for people to then come and say that their new post has a right to stay around because *see, that post is also still open!*

In other words, we don't want to have [broken windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) around for others to use as an excuse to throw some more stones.

Your question was a request for an external resource, something that is explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow, as such posts attract bike-shedding opinions and spam. Specifically, your post was brought to the attention of the moderator that closed it because a spammy answer was added to it.

Questions about external resources are off-topic on just about any Stack Exchange site, for these same reasons, with the exception of Software Recommendations, see [Where can I ask a question about finding general software that meets certain requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199411/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-finding-general-software-that-meets-certain-req)

Comment: Sounds like it actually took 2 years until a moderator accidentally found that "broken window"... In that case... Sorry, now it makes sense!

Comment: Yes, sometimes it can take a while; there are thousands of new questions every day posted to SO so visibility for an individual post can be limited.