# Where to ask for information about cloud integration

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I'm currently starting my internship, and I need to gather knowledge related with the integration of cloud services (SaaS).

I'm currently comparing integration platforms available in the market (iPaaS and similars), and the next steps are to analyze approaches to integrate services, and also look for open-source libraries related with the integration of services.

My question is in which Stack Exchange site should I ask for people's opinion on these issues?

Comment: Nowhere on SE will you get your market research done for free.  Even if allowed somewhere, your question is hugely broad and under-specified.

Comment: Questions asking for opinions are pretty much off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites. See: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm currently starting my internship, and I need to gather knowledge related with the integration of cloud services (SaaS). I'm currently comparing integration platforms available in the market (iPaaS and similars), and the next steps are to analyze approaches to integrate services,

That's great.  I've participated in something similar, recently.  For my part, I investigated Azure (as I've already some experience using it). Another team member investigated AWS.  A third investigated other cloud platforms.  It was a pretty large undertaking because of the breadth of these services, and how specific goals can be fulfilled through different services (for different prices and costs of development!) offered on each.

> and also look for open-source libraries related with the integration of services.

That's a good idea, however [software recommendations are generally off topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199411/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-finding-general-software-that-meets-certain-req).  There is a child site where you can--[softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)--but I'm not sure you'll get any more results asking there than you would searching through any one of the major search engines.  Their [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) are pretty strict.

> My question is in which Stack Exchange site should I ask for people's opinion on these issues?

Sorry, [asking for opinions is specifically off topic on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff). SE isn't a forum, and as such doesn't really support discussions well.  We do have chat, at which you might find people willing to discuss your requirements, but that's as close as you're going to get, unfortunately.