# Abstract questions for insights

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On which sub-platform of Stack Exchange would the following question fit?

I don't care for tools used or code, but just insights on the matter of the issue.

Question:

> I have a platform with multiple *users* that can post items themselves and *viewers* can see these items.
> The *users* can also bulk-import items to the platform.
> When *user1* bulk-imports a lot of items, the viewer only sees the bulk import items one after another. And the other items of the other users are only viewable after the viewer scrolls past *user1's* bulk post.
>
> How would I make bulk importing items less intrusive for the other single uploaded items?

FYI: the question I'm posing is also the question that I want to post on said sub-platform, but for this I would like to know where to go with this question.

Comment: What's "the platform" in question here?

Comment: A CMS like website. Would this help the question to change this?

Comment: If there was a site specific to the platform in question, yes.  The answer would probably involve uploading content to a temporary table and moving the content to the primary table only when the batch is complete.  This would ease the load on the front end and give you a back-out option if the bulk load failed for some reason.

Comment: There is no specific platform yet. The primary / secondary table is a nice idea. How could I sparsely send data from table a to b. Like a cron job every day to send 5 items?

Comment: Check this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199411/282094 and see if any on this list seem to fit the *kind of answer* you want to receive: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/282094 - different sites focus on the problem from different angles.

Comment: @Rob I think the second link is exactly what I need. Thanks for the tip.