# Where should I ask a question for a software recommendation for any OS?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question to solve a problem within any OS available (Windows desktop, web/Google Chrome plugin, and Android). It relates to [text-to-speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-to-speech) in mixed language texts for language learning.

As reposting a question is forbidden or discouraged, to which Stack Exchange site is it best to post?

My short list is

- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)
- [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

I would prefer a desktop solution, but I find the Super User community most restrictive. Also the chances to get what I need for free/easily are greater with *Web Applications* or *Android Enthusiasts*.

I do not know what app is the best for the task, but I can downplay that aspect, or pretend I already use a specific app but need to overcome few issues.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the question, this is impossible to answer, but it sounds like what you want is a recommendation for some sort of software.  Is that correct?

Comment: would it be fine with meta rules to reveal the question?

Comment: @Serge There is no rule against revealing the question; ensure that it's clear what is included to clarify the kind of recommendation you are looking for. Most questions asking for [se] site recommendation do not require the intended question to be asked but sometimes might be helpful for answerers to write a more specific site recommendation. Learn more at the [tag:site-recommendation] tag wiki -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info. P.S. Your shortlist doesn't look short compared with the list having 182 sites looks OK.

Comment: Reading texts in different languages/alphabets. I realize it's doable with some proper tts cloud service, but seems overkill. For small text/number of language switches murf.ai seems good. For learning large vocabulary a memory card app might work better but the few I tried do not allow easy bulk upload. When asked on software recommendations, got advice to subscribe to chatgpt 4.

Comment: For the moment I just installed one language reader which ignores unfamiliar alphabets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can ask a question for a software recommendation in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/14228).

Other sites might allow that type of question, like [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com), [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexhange.com) and [GenAI](https://genai.stackexchange.com).

##### Ask Different

The software should be compatible with Apple devices. See [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2180/274411)

##### GenAI

Asking for a recommendation for a generative AI might be on-topic in GenAI. See [Are questions asking for recommendations on-topic? In such case, what are our guidelines for such questions?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/158)

#### Questions that may require recommending software

Typically, the following sites don't allow questions asking for software recommendations. Still, if you ask a "very well received" question that can't be solved with what you have tried, you might get a recommendation as a workaround.

The best is that you ask in the respective per-site child Metas.

##### Super User

The app should run on computers. See [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5372).
*This is included first because the above link was used as inspiration to make a similar post on the following sites*.

##### Android Enthusiasts

The app should run on Android devices. See [How do I ask a question requiring recommending a product?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1289/71386)

---

> Serge is correct. Questions seeking software recommendations on Android Enthusiasts will be closed or migrated to Software Recommendations SE: softwarerecs.stackexchange.com –
> End Anti-Semitic Hate [18 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393888/where-should-i-ask-a-question-for-a-software-recommendation-for-any-os/393889?noredirect=1#comment1317386_393889)

---

> @EndAnti-SemiticHate Do you have recent direct experience asking software recommendation questions or using moderation privileges on these questions on Android Enthusiasts? Could you please provide recent examples?
> Rubén  [10 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393888/where-should-i-ask-a-question-for-a-software-recommendation-for-any-os/393889?noredirect=1#comment1317498_393889)

---

> @Rubén Yes. I am the top reviewer of the Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange (see android.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/stats). I am also a moderator of the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange (see softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). –
> End Anti-Semitic Hate [16 mins ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393888/where-should-i-ask-a-question-for-a-software-recommendation-for-any-os/393889?noredirect=1#comment1317552_393889)

---

##### Web Applications

The app should run on a Web browser. See [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/88163)

##### Related

- [Where can I ask a question about finding general software that meets certain requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199411/289691)

Comment: I think android enthusiasts are NOT allowed to ask for recommendations, but if you ask something how to this or they say in Android 10+ , the question will be tolerated

Comment: @Serge Your mileage might vary. Asking a good question on a site where a question is on topic increases the chances of having a satisfactory experience. Still, there are no warranties that the user experience will be the same across all the SE sites whenever they ask a question. To have the best insights into your experience, look at the recent participation around the related tags. Still, Keep your expectations broad and open: as SE  has entry-low barriers, there are opportunities for getting valuable contributions from bypassers.

Comment: Serge is correct.  Questions seeking software recommendations on Android Enthusiasts will be closed or migrated to Software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate Do you have recent direct experience asking software recommendation questions or using moderation privileges on these questions on [android.se]? Could you please provide recent examples?

Comment: @Rubén Yes. I am a top reviewer of the Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange (see https://android.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/stats).  I also have been a moderator of the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange since 2018 (see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).