# Where should I ask questions for asking which software library or API or framework to use for specific set of objective requirements?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I understand that the reason for asking questions that solicit opinions or suggestions is to avoid subjective answers and that we want the questions here to be answerable by an objective and definite answer.

But what if I have defined a set of requirements and the question isn't about what's the best out there but rather what could satisfy a set of objective requirements? Isn't that enough to make the question legitimate enough to be asked here?

Comment: Probably https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Note re: dupe, at the moment that's sort of in the middle of a messy dupe chain. I think that question can probably be polished off for modern times and reopened.

Comment: I assumed we do have different justifications for asking the same questions that we know are off-topic but legitimate.

Comment: Actually, I could transform my question in such a way it would not ask which library. But that would be equivalent to posting a lot of questions asking how to accomplish my objectives for every known library out there.

Comment: So actually, that puts that specific rule to be questionable in my opinion.

Comment: Just ask your question on Softwarerecs, that's what it's for. State requirements, get a recommendation.  Don't overthink it. :)

Comment: Ah; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199411/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-finding-general-software-that-meets-certain-req?noredirect=1&lq=1 is a way better dupe target. There we go. I just spent the last 10 minutes wading through chains of dupe links and old posts. Jeez.

Comment: And so I asked the question there. But it feels like it lacks the audience I need as my question is quite specialized to a java programming which is normally asked on SO. I think they seriously need to revisit the rules instead. :(

Comment: @supertonsky There's also the chat rooms, btw, e.g. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java